# How do I establish a link/relationship between objects?

Tags: java

```
public class MainClass {
    ArrayList<Man> mans = new ArrayList<Man>();
    // I'm filling in this arraylist, but I'm not writing those parts because I want to summarize the 
    //code. 
}

public class Man {
    int index_father, index_son;
    String name;
    public Man(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Some guys in this community of men have a father-son relationship. My question is that:
I'm looking for a neater way to build this father-son relationship.

I tried to establish this relationship with integers (example: which_father shows the directory where the man's father is in the 'mans' list) but this has some disadvantages:
1-When creating objects, I always have to create sons after fathers. because:

```
private void createMan() {
    Man man = new Man("Ethan");
    man.index_father = 4;
    mans.add(man);
    mans.get(4).index_son = mans.indexOf(man);
}
```

If we haven't created the father yet, the 4th element of mans will not have been created yet.
2- In cases where I delete an element from the mans arraylist, which_fathers will not show the correct father man.

I may not know enough about Java, but there must be an easy way to establish a connection between objects (like the father-son relationship in this example), right?

Comment: Is that the only relationship you want to establish between your objects? Or are you building a family tree? Is `Man` the only class you have?  Storing indices to an array list in the class is definitely not the way, because those indices can change. Try to add more context. And describe all the relationships. And what's the data source?

Comment: @AmalK I understand what you mean, but the actual code contains nearly 10,000 lines of code. I wrote this code to summarize the problem. Suppose you have a lot of family relationships. Most Needed Rabbit's answer does not apply to me because I have to gather all the people in one place. This is because for example Ethan's son 'Jack' and George's son 'Jacob' are friends and go to play ball. In such a case, to invoke the Jacob object, we first need to reach Jacob's father. Because Jacob is in George's object.

Comment: @vitaliis Your edit makes the post inconsistent. There are no "men" in the code, only "mans". They really mean "4th element of **mans**", not men. The same for "from the **mans** ArrayList".

Comment: Ah, sorry. You can edit it back

Comment: @vitaliis I don't edit. I rejected the suggested edit due to this though.

Comment: Sorry for my grammer

Comment: @HangeZoë It's normal to call it one man and two men, and it would have been a mistake not to do that in normal text. But you can call your variables whatever you like. In this case, I'd even say that "mans" make it more visibly a List, than "men", since it's just a one letter change and man/men are easily confused when looking at code :) You're within your right to do a rollback on the edit, if you wish to do so.

Comment: oh makes sense, got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `List<Man>` to represent sons in `Man` class:

```
public class Man {
    String name;
    List<Man> sons = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Man(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

I think OOP can help to simplify things:

```
public class Person {
    Sex sex;
    String name;
    List<Person> children = new ArrayList<>();
    Person partner; // husband/wife

    public Person(String name, Sex sex){
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
    
    public void marryTo(Person person){
        this.partner = person;
        person.setPartner(person);
    }

    public void setChildFromMarriage(Person child){
        children.add(child);
        partner.getChildren().add(child);
    }

    public enum Sex {
        MAN, WOMAN
    }
}
```

You can keep a `List<Person>`.

Usage:

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Jordan", Person.Sex.MAN),
        new Person("Tim", Person.Sex.MAN),
        new Person("Sarah", Person.Sex.WOMAN)
);

// Let's marry Jordan to Sarah
Person jordan = getPersonByName(people, "Jordan");
Person sarah = getPersonByName(people, "Sarah");
jordan.marryTo(sarah);

Person child = new Person("Jordan Jr", Person.Sex.MAN);
// We can add the child to people list if we want
jordan.setChildFromMarriage(child);

// Let's change their child name using Sarah's reference. 
getPersonByName(sarah.getChildren(), "Jordan Jr").setName("Bob");

System.out.println(child.getName()); // Bob

private static Person getPersonByName(List<Person> people, String name) {
    return people.stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getName().equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

Output:

```
Bob
```

Comment: yes but actually my code is much more complex. There are so many more relationships, and in that case it just doesn't work.

Comment: If you will add more details, I will try to improve my answer.

Comment: Imagine that these people have a mother, father, and wife. Emma and Eric husband and wife. Ethan is their son too. in this case it won't work to put the object inside the object (as in the example you gave). I have to gather all the people on a list and build relationships between them.

Comment: @HangeZoë I think this approach is too complex. See my edit

Comment: we will need to assign our child(ethan) both inside the eric object and inside the emma object. we will have to assign emma as eric's wife and eric as emma's wife. I think its complicated. and it would be much more complicated if we added other relationships.

Comment: eric's child and emma's child are the same person and one object. if we use the way you said, there will be two ethan objects inside emma and inside eric. When we increase the age characteristic of one, the other will not increase automatically. Because they are two separate objects.

Comment: @HangeZoë No, both parents will reference the same object.

Comment: @HangeZoë I have added an example to reflect this

Comment: can i ask one more little question? is there any difference between ' List<Person> children = new ArrayList<>(); '   and   ' ArrayList<Person> children = new ArrayList<>(); '

Comment: @HangeZoë Sure. List is an interface. ArrayList is one of the implementations of List.

Comment: but when creating an object, "initializing the list object with the ArrayList constructor" and "initializing the arraylist object with the ArrayList constructor" must be the same thing, right? I've always used the latter until now, so I was wondering if I'm doing it right. Actually I wonder if I did a lot of things right as I don't even know the basic information you showed me about oop.

Comment: @HangeZoë By keeping `List` interface instead of `ArrayList` we are following a good practice to make the code resilient to change. Imagine we have come to the conclusion that in order to improve the performance, we need to use the `LinkedList` implementation instead of `ArrayList`. If we kept `List` instead of `ArrayList` we will have to change just the initialization.

Comment: Don't worry, you are on the right path, and I can see that by the fact that you posted a question here.

Comment: thanks for your words. I've posted an answer the bottom of the question to make sure I understand correctly. Can you check? Even if it's the slightest mistake/misunderstanding, I'd appreciate it if you correct it.

Answer (score 1):

So what I have to do is use references instead of integers.
I thought that the objects we created were not references, but the object itself. I thought that when we assign an object to an object, the object on the left takes all the properties of the object on the right and we have two independent objects. But what actually happens is that the object reference on the left takes the object reference on the right, and we have two references and one object.
So the only way to actually create an object is to use **new Constructor()**.

I changed the code to:

```
public class Person {
    String Name;
    Gender gender;
    Person father;
    Person mother;
    Person partner;
    ArrayList<Person> childs = new ArrayList<Person>();
    
    public enum Gender {
        MAN, WOMAN
    }
    
    public Person(String name, Gender gender){
        this.Name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    
    public void marryTo(Person person){
        this.partner = person;
        person.partner = this;
    }
    
     public void setChildFromMarriage(Person child){
         childs.add(child);
         partner.childs.add(child);
     }
}
```

..........................................................................................
..........................................................................................

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            MainClass obj = new MainClass ();
            obj.run ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
    
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    
    public void run () {
        Person p; 
        
        p = new Person("Jordan", Person.Gender.MAN);
        persons.add(p);
        p = new Person("Sarah", Person.Gender.WOMAN);
        persons.add(p);
        
        persons.get(0).marryTo(persons.get(1));
        
        p = new Person("Jordan Jr", Person.Gender.MAN);
        persons.add(p);
        persons.get(0).setChildFromMarriage(persons.get(2));
        
        persons.get(1).childs.get(0).Name = "Bob";
        
        System.out.println(persons.get(2).Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bob
```